# Rails includes multiple association with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to achieve the following query, but I encounter some troubles.

Here is the relationship.

```
Comment belongs_to Product
Product has_many Product_infos
```

And below is what I need to achieve,

```
@comments = Comment.order(id: :desc)
                   .includes([product: :product_infos])
                   .where('product.product_infos.name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

But it threw this error

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'product.product_infos.name' in 'where
>   clause': SELECT  `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE
>   (product.product_infos.name like '%Search_term%') ORDER BY
>   `comments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0

What did I miss?

Comment: Try move order after where with `comment.id`

Comment: @iGian it threw the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.
Try this adding `.references(:product_infos)`

```
Comment
  .order(id: :desc).includes([product: :product_infos])
  .where('product_infos.name like ?', "%#{params[:search]}%")
  .references(:product_infos)
  .inspect
```

See API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-references

When you need to use a more straight condition, you can use this syntax:

```
Comment
  .includes([product: :product_infos])
  .where(product_infos: {name: "another info on product one"})
  .inspect
```

Comment: You save my day!!!!! I did try the second way and it works, but seems I need to use `Like` operator, I need to use the first solution.